# How does HibernateTemplate and Spring @Transactional work together?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

We use HibernateTemplate in our DAOs for all the CRUD operations.

My question is, we use spring `@Transactional` on the services, Because the spring is managing the transactions, how does the *HibernateTemplate* behave in the senario where I update multiple DAOs. Meaning does *HibernateTemplate* use same session across  different DAOs when Spring `@Transactional` is used?

```
@Transactional
public boolean testService(SObject test)[

     dao1.save(test.getOne());
     dao2.save(test.gettwo());

}
```

This is how the DAO class looks:

```
public class GenericHibernateDao<T, PK extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport
.
.
.
public PK save(T newInstance) {
    return (PK) getHibernateTemplate().save(newInstance);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `HibernateTransactionManager` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html) is pretty clear about this:

> This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single Hibernate SessionFactory for transactional data access, but it also supports direct DataSource access within a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource). This allows for mixing services which access Hibernate and services which use plain JDBC (without being aware of Hibernate)! Application code needs to stick to the same simple Connection lookup pattern as with org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager (i.e. DataSourceUtils.getConnection or going through a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy).

You're fine as long as you are accessing the connection through helper classes that are aware of the connection proxy such as `DataSourceUtils` (and the `JdbcTemplate` uses that behind the hood)